# Class ABC is implemented in both Py2app App and System Library. One of the two will be used

Tags: pyqt, py2app

I'm attempting to package [Mnemosyne](http://mnemosyne-proj.org), an application that uses PyQt, on Mac OS Lion via Py2app.

I'm getting several errors like the following:

> - objc[2826]: Class QCocoaView is implemented in both
>     /Volumes/Bullfrog/patrick/m2/./dist/Mnemosyne.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libQtGui.4.dylib
>     and /opt/local/lib/libQtGui.4.dylib. One of the two will be used.
>     Which one is undefined.
> - objc[2826]: Class QCocoaWindow is implemented in both
>     /Volumes/Bullfrog/patrick/m2/./dist/Mnemosyne.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libQtGui.4.dylib
>     and /opt/local/lib/libQtGui.4.dylib. One of the two will be used.
>     Which one is undefined.

The first version of the class is the one used in Py2App and is the one that should be used (I am trying to make the app standalone).  The second is the system Qt that I installed via MacPorts.  What do I have to add to the application to make it use the bundled Qt and not the system Qt?

And also several statements like this:

> On Mac OS X, you might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the
>   same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt
>   binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of
>   binaries are being loaded. QObject::moveToThread: Current thread
>   (0x10246c880) is not the object's thread (0x106985d00). Cannot move to
>   target thread (0x10246c880)

Honestly I don't really understand how to do what I need to do here just based on this error message (I'm not a coder; I'm just doing my best to package the software).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This article](http://www.thetoryparty.com/2009/08/27/pyqt-and-py2app-seriously-i-dont-know-what-to-do-with-you-when-youre-like-this/) gives a solution: simply add a blank qt.conf file in the application's Content/Resources directory.